# I have a requirement where I need to dynamically convert column values into column headers in Azure SQL DW

Tags: t-sql, transpose, dynamic-sql, azure-synapse

table structure is something like below (total number of record goes upto 150)

[image]

After transposing, table result set should be like below where .... represent n number of columns

[image]

Basically, my idea is to create a temp table on the fly and have its column names defined from the select statement to get result-set shown in 2nd picture

Query should be something like ---

```sql
SELECT * INTO #Cols FROM (select * of above resultset)A WHERE 1=2
```

Note:- Please refrain from using FOR XML Path as Azure SQL DW currently doesn't support this feature.

Comment: You need to fix your design; that's the real solution here.

Comment: design goes like that only.

Comment: No, the design doesn't. It should be normalised, like the result set you want. Also, how do you tell the data from one employee to the next in that table? If you only have those 2 columns, then your data's integrity is already completely lost.

Comment: Apparently, Azure data warehouse supports `STRING_AGG`, so you can use that to make your dynamic statement and then execute it. Then you can use that statement to fix your design and normalise it.

Comment: values you are seeing are all dummy..I am not worried about the data integrity here..My motto is to create a temp table eventually having name of columns as values I get after transposing my parent table. Hope that makes sense to you

Comment: (1) I agree with @Larnu first comment that you **probably** should fix the design +1, (2) BUT I TOTALLY DISAGREE with the second comment! As much as I understand this is Azure Data Warehouse and it is NOT meant to follow relational model! While in OLTP database we might want to follow Codd's 12 rules and Normalization in some cases, this is totally not relevant to DW where we should prepare data for reporting, ETL, data mining, analytics and so on. In most cases (this is like red flag but not always true) if I see DW which follow the Normalization rules then I know the wrong tool was selected.

Comment: Good day @surajkumar, In forst glance this looks like a simple case of dynamic query. note that Azure Synapse supports sp_executesql and it supports PIVOT. If you will provide full DDL+DML+expected result, then we will be able to  discuss specific solution (sry, but without DDL+DML which you should provide I usually do not spend time on testing solutions). Ping if you add the missing information :-)

Answer (score 2):

I have no way of validating this works, however, from my searchfu `STRING_AGG` is available on Azure Data warehouse. I *assume* it has access to `QUOTENAME` and it does have access to [dynamic statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-develop-dynamic-sql) so you can do something like this:

```sql
DECLARE @SQL_Start nvarchar(4000) = N'SELECT ',
        @SQL_Columns nvarchar(4000),
        @SQL_End nvarchar(4000) = N'INTO SomeTable FROM YourTable WHERE 1 = 2;';

SET @SQL_Columns = (SELECT STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(ColumnName),',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ColumnName)
                    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ColumnName
                          FROM YourTable) YT);

EXEC(@SQL_Start + @SQL_Columns + @SQL_End);
```

But, again, the *real* solution is to fix your design.